Распаковка zip архива в PostgreSQL встроенным методом
Задача:
В поле с типом BLOB(text или bytea) лежит zip архив из json строк.
Надо распаковать архив и построчно обработать записи(вставить в таблицу с некоторым преобразованием)
В Oracle есть встроенная утилита UTL_COMPRESS и с ее помощью я могу распаковать данные так:
UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS(BLOB_CONTENT)

Есть ли аналог данной утилиты в PostgreSQL?

В штатном комплекте (или среди contrib модулей) нет SQL-функций по работе с zip данными.
